# Git doesn't delete directories and files in versioned directories

Tags: git, permissions, conflict

Let's say I have a folder structure in my local repository:

```
Folder A
 |_ Folder B
    - File 1
    - File 2
```

Someone in the team deletes `Folder B` and its files and pushes some other changes into the upstream branch which I then get with a `git pull`. Looking into my local repo, the changes are there, but `Folder B` and all files inside of it is too, they simply weren't deleted. On my next `git push`, it will add the folder to the remote repo again, resulting in a conflict when other team members are trying to merge.

What is going on? I checked directory permissions, they are `775`, and so are files.

EDIT: Clarifying that files within `Folder B` weren't deleted either in local repository.

Comment: Was `File 1` tracked ? and deleted from the central repo by that commit you mention ?

Comment: File 1 was tracked and deleted by a pull request / merge on the main branch.

Comment: ok ; and running `git pull` : a. did not trigger any conflict, and b. didn't delete `File 1` from your disk ? (that would be the odd part)

Comment: In one case, git triggered a merge conflict. In another case, there was no conflict, and `File 1` was not deleted. So I had a tracked file `framework/themes/B/file1.tpl` that was in my local repo, where `themes/B` didn't even exist in the remote repo.

Comment: How did you resolve the conflict in the first case ?

Comment: I didn't, I deleted my local folder and `git clone`'d the remote repo again, since I didn't know what other files might have been kept in my repo that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

Git does not store directories at all.  (Git doesn't use the word "version" either, but it is clear what you mean here.)

The trick is that when you make a commit, the commit has files whose names *look like* they have directories in them.  A commit might have a file named `path/to/file.ext`, for instance.  This does not mean there is a `path` directory, nor a `path/to` directory.  There is merely a *file* whose name is `path/to/directory`, stored inside that commit.<sup>1</sup>  That doesn't work in your *OS* of course; your operating system, whether it's Linux or Windows or macOS or whatever probably<sup>2</sup> demands that Git create a directory named `path`, and then in that folder, create one named `to`, and then create the file named `file.ext` inside `path/to`.  So Git will do that when it must, to satisfy the OS.  But Git didn't *store* `path` and `to` separately.<sup>3</sup>

So: what's going on?

> Someone in the team deletes `Folder B` and pushes some other changes into the upstream branch ...

Each commit holds a *full snapshot of every file that Git knows about*.  To make a *new* commit—which simply adds to the repository; all the existing commits remain—Git creates a new snapshot of every file that it knows about.  But which files are those?

The answer lies in that index thing that so far has been mentioned only in the footnotes.  Git keeps, in this thing that it calls the *index* or the *staging area* or (rarely these days) the *cache*, a *list of every file that should go into the next commit*.  This isn't *just*  a list of files: it also contains, pre-computed, the *snapshot* of that file, as it should appear in the next commit.  The file snapshots inside commits are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  When you run `git add` on a file, this *copies the file into the index*, compressing it and de-duplicating it (so that if the content matches any existing file in *any* commit, it's automatically shared with that earlier commit).

When you run `git commit`, what goes into the new commit is *every file in the index*.  That's it—that's how Git makes a new commit, from whatever is in Git's index.  The files in your working area, which are ordinary everyday files, are not consulted.  Only what's in Git's *index* matters.

For someone to "delete `Folder B`" is technically impossible as `Folder B` is not *in* any commits.  What is in the commits (that have them anyway) are files named `Folder A/Folder B/File 1` and so on.  If someone makes a new commit that lacks `Folder A/Folder B/File 1`, that commit simply lacks the file.  If it lacks *every* file, then checking out that commit removes the files from your work-area **provided** they were in Git's index at the time you told Git: *switch from my previously-checked-out commit, that has those files, to this here different commit that doesn't have the files*.

Remember, `git checkout commit` or `git checkout branch` is telling Git: *remove whatever's in my work-tree and in your index and replace it in your index and my work-tree with the stuff from the commit I'm switching to*.  For this to work, Git has to take some files away.  But it only takes away *indexed* files, which are typically those that came out of some previous commit.<sup>4</sup>  Any files that are in your work-tree, but not in Git's index, are *untracked* files, and Git will not touch those files.

If Git removes *all* the files from your OS-required `Folder A/Folder B` path, Git will also remove the `Folder B` directory.<sup>5</sup>  But if there's any file remaining, that did not get removed because of the change of commits, Git *won't* delete the `Folder B` directory, as your OS requires it to exist so as to hold those untracked files.

> On my next `git push`, it will add the folder to the remote repo again ...

Any existing commits you have in your repository at the time you run `git pull` are not changed by the `git pull`.  (No part of any existing commit can ever change.)  If you use `git pull --rebase`, however, you direct your own Git to *copy* some of your existing commits to new-and-improved ones.  If these commits have modified `Folder A/Folder B/...` files, those modifications have to be preserved.  This may produce modify/delete conflicts; if you resolve them by keeping your files, that will reintroduce the files.  If you use a `git pull` that performs a `git merge`, commits you have that they don't have to be merged in, which also involves combining work and can produce conflicts and/or restore files.

If you simply preserve your existing commits (e.g., by working on different branches and *not* combining your work with their work), that leaves the `Folder A/Folder B/...` files in your work-tree and in Git's index, and new commits you make will continue to have those files in them.  Someone—whether that's you or someone else—will, later, have to combine your work with their work in some way, using merge or rebase or whatever process you like (merge and rebase are the primary two processes that Git provides).  This may encounter modify/delete conflicts, which must be resolved.  That's entirely normal.

---

<sup>1</sup>The technique that Git uses when storing files is to store the names in one place, and each file's content in another.  The names wind up in something that Git calls its index, which is actually just a file: a file full of data, including path-name strings with embedded slashes in them.

<sup>2</sup>Definitely.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, Git actually *does* store them separately, but only in the commits themselves, and it doesn't "version" them in the sense you're thinking of.  This stands in sharp contrast to, e.g., Subversion and ClearCase, which *do* version the directories.  Git has this strange relationship with the directory names, though, translating them back into that flat index file.  The index can only store *file* names, not directory names, and as a result, Git is unable to store an empty directory.

<sup>4</sup>If you have run `git add` or `git rm`, you can have adjusted what's in Git's index at this point, so that it does not match the checked-out commit.  This complicates everything.  The general description here assumes that Git's index matches your current commit, and all the *tracked* files—all the files that are in Git's index—also match the work-tree copies, so that your work-tree is "clean" except for maybe having various untracked files.

<sup>5</sup>At least, it is supposed to.  Back in the bad old days of Git 1.6 and 1.7 I could swear I saw cases where this failed.

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you are saying, even though I might have to read it once or twice more. If we have a merge conflict after pulling some changes, then at least I know where to look for the files. But we had a case where one team member refactored 5 framework themes in 2. When I pulled his changes, 2 themes were deleted, and 1 wasn't. I only noticed this by coincidence. So over time, I will have a local repository that doesn't reflect the remote repository in different places of the code. This is not exactly why we use version control, and I'm still unsure how to prevent it?

Comment: If I do `git pull --rebase`, then my local changes will be reapplied on top of the remote changes. What would that mean in case of `Folder B`?

Comment: Sorry about delay, I've been away-from-computer a lot. The main thing to learn here though is that Git isn't about *files* per se, it's about *commits* (that then contain files) and everything you do is manipulation of a graph of commits. This is what leads to the manipulation of individual files. For a good background see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/). As to rebase: yes, your local changes get "re-performed" as it were. The fundamental concept here is the cherry-pick operation, which is also a merge, but a little bit of a weird merge.